# How is $3\pi-10$ element of $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$?

Tags: trigonometry

How is $3\pi-10$ element of $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$?
According to me this means that $530$ is an element of $[-90,90]$. i.e. Range of $\arcsin$ function.

(Note:- I was trying to find the value of $\arcsin(\sin 10))$)

Comment: $\pi$ is in radians over here not degrees.

Comment: $\arcsin(\sin10))=\arcsin((-1)^3\sin(10-3\pi))=\arcsin(\sin(3\pi-10))$ and as $9<3\pi<10$ you get $0>3\pi-10>-1>-\frac\pi2$, so that this is in the domain where $x=\arcsin(\sin(x))$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're making the mistake of not converting everything into degrees and just the $\pi$ into degrees.

$$(3\pi-10) rad = (540-10\times 57.296)^{\circ}$$

$$= -32.96^{\circ} \in [-90^{\circ},90^{\circ}]$$

Comment: But wouldn't it change the value of pi/2 also????

Comment: Well,$\pi/2 rad = 90^{\circ}$. So what about it?

Comment: Well $-32.96$ degrees still falls in the interval $[-90º, 90º]$.

Comment: Note that $1$ rad $= 57.296^{\circ}$

Comment: Thats what im saying pi/2=90 degrees but youre saying it is equal to (180/2)*57.296

Comment: Well that's what my brain interpreted

Comment: NO. $\pi$ rad $= 180^{\circ}$. Now $\pi/2$ rad $=90^{\circ}$

Comment: $3\pi$ rad = $540^{\circ}$. $10$ rad = $572.96^{\circ}$. Therefore $(3\pi-10)$ rad = $-32.96^{\circ}$

Comment: Yeah with relaxed mind i got it